# Override public static

Tags: static, overriding, public, user-registration

How do I change the following files in function.php:

```
        if ( empty( $atts ) || ! isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            return '';
        }
        /**
         * Applies a filter to override the 'users_can_register' setting.
         *
         * The 'ur_register_setting_override' filter allows developers to customize
         * the 'users_can_register' setting by providing an alternative value.
         *
         * @param bool $default_value Default value retrieved from the 'users_can_register' setting.
         */
        $users_can_register = apply_filters( 'ur_register_setting_override', get_option( 'users_can_register' ) );

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if ( ! $users_can_register ) {
                /**
                 * Applies a filter to customize the pre-form message for user registration.
                 *
                 * @param string $default_message Default pre-form message.
                 */
                return apply_filters( 'ur_register_pre_form_message', '<p class="alert" id="ur_register_pre_form_message">' . __( 'Only administrators can add new users.', 'user-registration' ) . '</p>' );
            }
        } else {
            /**
             * Applies a filter to customize the capability required for user registration.
             *
             * @param string $default_capability Default user capability.
             */
            $current_user_capability = apply_filters( 'ur_registration_user_capability', 'create_users' );

            if ( ! current_user_can( $current_user_capability ) ) {
                global $wp;

                $user_ID      = get_current_user_id();
                $user         = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_ID );
                $current_url  = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
                $display_name = ! empty( $user->data->display_name ) ? $user->data->display_name : $user->data->user_email;
                /**
                 * Applies a filter to customize the pre-form message for user registration.
                 *
                 * @param string $default_message Default pre-form message.
                 */
                /* translators: 1: Link and username of user 2: Logout url */
                return apply_filters( 'ur_register_pre_form_message', '<p class="alert" id="ur_register_pre_form_message">' . sprintf( __( 'You are currently logged in as %1$1s. %2$2s', 'user-registration' ), '<a href="#" title="' . $display_name . '">' . $display_name . '</a>', '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( $current_url ) . '" title="' . __( 'Log out of this account.', 'user-registration' ) . '">' . __( 'Logout', 'user-registration' ) . '  &raquo;</a>' ) . '</p>', $user_ID );

            }
        }

        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '',
            ),
            $atts,
            'user_registration_form'
        );
        /**
         * Fires when rendering scripts for the 'user_registration_form' shortcode.
         *
         * The 'user_registration_form_shortcode_scripts' action allows developers
         * to enqueue custom scripts or perform actions related to the 'user_registration_form' shortcode.
         *
         * @param array $atts Shortcode attributes passed for customization.
         */
        do_action( 'user_registration_form_shortcode_scripts', $atts );

        ob_start();
        self::render_form( $atts['id'] );

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

I want to remove this code:

```
if ( ! $users_can_register ) {
                /**
                 * Applies a filter to customize the pre-form message for user registration.
                 *
                 * @param string $default_message Default pre-form message.
                 */
                return apply_filters( 'ur_register_pre_form_message', '<p class="alert" id="ur_register_pre_form_message">' . __( 'Only administrators can add new users.', 'user-registration' ) . '</p>' );
            }
```

I'm currently not allowing everyone to register, but this form plugin isn't working either. If I remove the above code, it can work fine. However I don't want to change the original code of the plugin.

I don't allow someone to register using wordpress' native registration feature. I want my customers to register using a custom registration form. Many of my customers register using the default registration form, this makes me confused about dealing with them.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide an answer.